# Deploying Rails App in DigitalOcean with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I'm learning Capistrano ( this my 2nd day of learning ) .. I tried to deploy my rails test-app in digitalocean but I got an error in `cap production deploy`. `cap production deploy:check` was finished properly.

This is the error:
    cap Aborted

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host IP_ADDRESS: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors


SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

    Tasks: TOP => git:create_release
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host     IP_ADDRESS: git exit status: 2
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: fatal: Not a valid object name
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Did you check the ssh key or host?

Comment: are you able to enter to remove server by ssh (`ssh your_user@19x.x.x.x.`)

Comment: I already figure it out why I got that error, I didn't push my app in the remote repository. Thank you!